# XPATH, Select an specific valid value from a Flex container

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, automation, bdd

As the title implies I'm currently facing some issues trying to sort this out, the thing is I have an horizontal flex container which shows the *Qtrs/Years* in order to assign a valid one to a Package Rotation as you'll see on the bottom snippet there are 3 types of "status/classes" that I have to consider, given that certain quarters/years can be set as "Not valid" meaning I shouldn't consider them for the selection itself, leaving me to actually have to first search for the valid quarters (***class="quarter valid*** and ***class="quarter valid selected***, the latter one being the one I currently have selected duh')

Then after actually getting only the valid ones I need to be able to create an XPATH that allows me to travel through those options and be able to select them with an Index or preferably by text (eg: quarterNumber = '3Q' and year = "2021")

Basically the html/dom for that part is this:

```html
<div class="quartersContainer"</div>
    <div class="quarter">
        <div class="quarterNumber">1Q</div>
        <div class="year">2021</div>
        <div class="releasedIndicator"></div>
        <div class="quarterbar-editing-mode"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="quarter">
        <div class="quarterNumber">2Q</div>
        <div class="year">2021</div>
        <div class="releasedIndicator"></div>
        <div class="quarterbar-editing-mode"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="quarter valid selected">
        <div class="quarterNumber">3Q</div>
        <div class="year">2021</div>
        <div class="releasedIndicator"></div>
        <div class="quarterbar-editing-mode"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="quarter valid">
        <div class="quarterNumber">4Q</div>
        <div class="year">2021</div>
        <div class="releasedIndicator"></div>
        <div class="quarterbar-editing-mode"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="quarter">
        <div class="quarterNumber">1Q</div>
        <div class="year">2022</div>
        <div class="releasedIndicator"></div>
        <div class="quarterbar-editing-mode"></div>
    </div>
```

What I have so far is just this.... (I'm really new to this :( )

*//div[contains(@class,'quarter valid') and .//@class='quarterNumber' and .//@class='year']*

The whole point of this is to actually generate an XPATH that can be manipulated in a future or through a Behave Feature file for example so testers just have to actually change the **text** from something like 2Q - 2021 to 3Q - 2023 and it will be able to look for it.

Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated :')

Comment: you can combine variables into the xpath:
"//div[contains(@class,'quarter valid') and .//@class='" + quarterNumber + "' and .//@class='year']"

Comment: @DMart thanks for the answer man, nevertheless I'm currently missing the part where to actually assign a "customizable" text to it so I can actually use it for a feature file for example :(

Comment: It's a variable. Assign it's value however you want. Unless I'm misunderstanding what you're actually asking for...

Comment: @DMart, nevermind you were absolutely right hahaha my bad on that one, thanks !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @DMart is suggesting, do something like this

```
def build_xpath(year ,quarterNumber):
   return "//div[contains(@class,'quarter valid') and .//@class='" + year = "' and .//@class='" + quarterNumber + "']"
```

And then it's up to you how and with with what values you call build_xpath()

Comment: Thanks Siebe! using this just like you and DMart suggested, thanks a lot to both of you guys!